# Implementing JSONP function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am using JSONP my goal is simple the data returned must display in my div. The code currently does not display anything. I've also integrated jquery.jsonp.js within my project my path:

```
                 PRJFOLDER->WEBPages->JavaScript->query.jsonp.js
```

the index.html file is in the path:

```
                  PRJFOLDER->WEBPages->index.html
```

My Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          function getData(url, data, callback) {
             $.ajax({
              url : url,
              type : 'post',
              jsonp: "callback", // Needed for jsonp
              dataType: "jsonp", // Also needed for jsonp
              timeout : timeout,
              data : data || {},
              success : function(data) {
               callback(data);
              } // Omitted failure for this example
            });
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <script>
                var data = {};
                var url = 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/popular?callback=?'

                getData(url, {}, function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                data = result;
                });

                $('#post-result').append(JSON.stringify(data));
        </script>

       <div id='post-result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please assist me in displaying the output

Comment: What's `jquery.jsonp.js`?

Comment: If jsonp.js uses jQuery then you need to reorder your scripts

Comment: Your includes are in the wrong order.

Comment: You really don't need a plugin for JSONP.  You can just use `$.ajax`.  Just change `$.jsonp({` to `$.ajax({`, and add `"dataType": 'jsonp'`.  I'm assuming that's all the plugin is doing anyway.  Also, what do you expect `.append(data)` to do?  `.append()` expects a node (or a jQuery object or a HTML string), not an object.

Comment: Thanks i will try this. I was expecting append to attach the return result into the div container

Comment: @KSM: You can't just do `.append(data)`.  You'd need to loop over the data and add the values (format the data how you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove jsonp. There is no need for that.
Now remember that when you are using jsonp, the server will send a function as a return value instead of an object.

Luckily, jquery has support for jsonp and will give an object literal as the value.
Just make sure beforehand that your api url supports jsonp.

See the code below :

```
function getData(url, data, callback) {
 $.ajax({
  url : url,
  type : 'post',
  jsonp: "callback", // Needed for jsonp
  dataType: "jsonp", // Also needed for jsonp
  timeout : timeout,
  data : data || {},
  success : function(data) {
   callback(data);
  } // Omitted failure for this example
});
```

After this, you will need to make a function to receive the value :

```
var data = {};
var url = 'http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/popular?callback=yourFunction'

getData(url, {}, function(result) {
console.log(result);
data = result;
});
```

Now that you have got your data, you can easily add it in your html via templates or as raw text

Raw text :

```
$('#post-result').append(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Oh and I highly recommend you put your application code just before the closing body tag.